# Android : Enumerating on an String ArrayList after Closing and Restarting the App

Tags: android, string, list

I have a list of strings, let's say:

```
l = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
```

with 6 elements. After working with first 3 elements, for example (a, b, c), I close down my app. I again open my app and want to start my work from 4th element i.e. 'd'. How do I achieve this in Android? At present whenever I close my app, the list gets reset to first element. Again, in my case, the list is really long and when it is used by different users, I don't know a priori at what element a random user will close the app.

I want a method which can keep track of the last element being accessed before the app is closed, so that I can restart from that location (+1) element.

Comment: U can store the last known index in the shared preferences

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: Use shared preference and store the last accessed element and then use it, quite simple. @Samiksha

Answer (score 0):

Store the last traversed index in shared preferences and next time initialize the iteration with value from shared pref.

Let's say index was 3, int lastTraversedIndex = 3;

```
prefs.editor.putInt("index", lastTraversedIndex).commit();
```

When you start app get value from pref

```
int lastTraversedIndex = prefs.getInt("index", 0); //0 for first run
```

Use this index

```
if(lastTraversedIndex < list.size()) {
 for(int i = lastTraversedIndex; i<list.size(); i++) {
  //
 }
}
```